# Phonegap Cordova Error: Unexpected Token } in JSON at position 659

Tags: android, json, cordova, phonegap, html-framework-7

So this is really odd...

I'm trying to make a hybrid app with Framework7 by using Cordova / Phonegap. I'm new at this stuff and I'm just trying to run my (almost) blank app on my phone by running:

> cd {directory} phonegap run android

Not working... getting this error:

> Unexpected Token } in JSON at position 659

Now... WHAT Json file is this? I have so many and have no clue where to begin, and does it mean 659th line?? Or like the actual 659th position, as in characters?

Can someone help me out? Even though I haven't made much progress I don't want to start over :/